# How to ensure that an assigned employee has a required competence?

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming

I'm a complete noob in regards to constraint-programming and Google's OR-Tools.
I'm trying to assign employees to a certain workplace-day-shift combinations, with a constraint, that the employee must be capable of working on the specified workplace (the employee has the workplace id in their skills list).

What I've tried was a simple loop like this:

```
for employee in employees:
    for workplace in workplaces:
            model.Add(workplace.id in employee.skills)
```

But it seems that above constraint requires all employees to be capable of woking on every workplace, which is obviously not what I am after.

How should I construct such a constraint, that prevents an employee to be assigned to a workplace.id if it is not in employee.skills?

edit:

adding the problem description as per @Sembei Norimaki's request

employees is a list of objects of class Employee

```
@dataclass
class Employee:
    id: str 
    name: str
    skills: list  # list of workplace.id's an Employee can operate
    plan: list  # list of [day, shift] combinations an employee is available for work
```

workplaces is a list of objects of class Workplace

```
@dataclass
class Workplace:
    id: str
    no_of_shifts: int  # number (sum) of shifts that must be manned in a week
```

input:

- employees list
- workplaces list
- days list (consecutive days in a week)
- shifts list - [1, 2, 3] where 1 - morning, 2 - afternoon, 3 - night

constraints:

- at most one employee per day-workplace-shift
- at most one workplace-shift per day per employee
- sum of manned shifts on a workplace per week <= workplace.no_of_shifts
- workplace.id in employee.skills (an employee must be able to operate workspace)
- [day, shift] in employee.plan (an employee must be available)

objective:

- maximize sum of manned shifts per workplace per week

output:

- list of day, shift, employee, workplace combinations

  > (on day i, shift j, employee k works on workplace l)

Comment: Depends on some context. Assuming you got a linear-assignment problem like assignment-matrix of boolean variables: `assign = (N_WORKERS, N_WORKPLACES)`, incompatible (workplace not in skills) assignments are just a unit-fixing of the negated / 0-assigned variable: `model.Add(assign(worker, workplace) == 0)` (or any other equivalent form).

Comment: maybe something like `if workplace.id in employee.skills: model.Add(employee)`  what do you want to store in model? employees, workplaces?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I am storing employee-workplace-day-shift combinations as the variables, but I haven't considered NOT creating variables that do not meet the skill requirement. thank you, I think this will help me go forward.

Comment: @sascha can you actually modify variable values like that? thanks, this will come in handy!

Comment: put an example of what is inside employees, what is inside workplaces and what would you like to be inside model. Make a toy example where you show the input and desired output.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki edited the main post with the problem description